# Is there any dataset for problems common people are facing to build apps against?

Tags: data-request, programming

Let say I am dumb but not enough to stay home watch tv all day, so I decided to develop a open data application, now problem is what app can I build. So call it analysis I am looking for a dataset where I can get problems common people are facing to build application against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally difficult to build applications to scratch someone else's itch without having a vested interest in it (such as getting paid).

You're typically better off trying to find something that bothers you, and figure out how to solve or mitigate it.

If you really can't think of anything, there are hackathons and 'data jams' where they bring together people w/ programming skills & data experts to try to come up with uses for the data:

- [National Day of Civic Hacking](http://hackforchange.org/)
- [Capital Code Data Jam](http://capitolcode.mn.gov/) (MN)

You may also have local groups working on projects that you can get involved with.  Some meet virtually, others get together for regular 'hacknight' events, instead of it just being an annual or non-reoccuring thing:

- [Code For America](http://codeforamerica.org/)
- [Code For DC Hacknight](http://www.meetup.com/code-for-dc)
- [Random Hacks of Kindness](http://www.rhok.org/)

If you're a student, there are various 'summer of code' projects, where various projects solicit for things they need done, and students can get stipends to work on them.  (the other still needs doing, so if you're willing to volunteer, there's likely still work they need doing).  Here are a few, although there are other groups with similar programs:

- [Google Summer of Code](https://developers.google.com/open-source/soc/)
- [Rails Girls Summer of Code](http://railsgirlssummerofcode.org/)
- [ESA Summer of Code in Space](http://sophia.estec.esa.int/socis/)

And tomorrow & Wednesday is the [Mozilla Science Lab](http://mozillascience.org/blog/)'s [Summer Code Sprint](http://mozillascience.org/how-to-join-us-virtually-for-the-global-sprint-july-22-23/).

... and these are just a sampling of all of the various groups out there -- there's a whole lot more.  You can also reach out to various community groups and see if they have need for some programming help.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [Unanswered Questions at Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered).
Many are open data app ideas waiting for an implementer.

---

Also, travel is something that most people do from time to time, and it often leads them to all sorts of big or small problems (or at least situations where an app might help).

And there is a lot of open-licensed travel data available at [Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/):

- [Points Of Interest](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wikivoyage/files/) with tourism-oriented description and details
- [Guide articles](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wikivoyage/files/OxygenGuide/) about 25,000 destinations around the globe
- [Raw data dumps](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wikivoyage:Database_dump)
- Wikivoyage is linked with WikiData and other datasets, so that you can easily include pictures etc

Answer (score 3):

@Joe mentioned a number of [great resources for civic/open-source related apps/ideas](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3400/2976). Here are some resources for app ideas from the general public:

- [Ideas Watch: "startup inspiration from the crowd"](http://www.ideaswatch.com/startup-ideas/app#)
- [PreApps: App Ideas](http://www.preapps.com/app-ideas)
- [MyAppTemplates: "99 iPhone App Ideas That Could Make You Rich"](http://myapptemplates.com/99-iphone-app-ideas-that-could-make-you-rich-the-full-list/)
- [BuildItWith.Me: Ideas](http://builditwith.me/browse/ideas/) (by people looking for designers and/or developers to collaborate with)
- [Sub-Reddit: SomebodyMakeThis](http://www.reddit.com/r/SomebodyMakeThis/)
- [Twtspire: "fun ideas for apps and websites from twitter"](http://www.twtspire.com/app/)